# OneDrive not integrated with Windows Explorer on Windows 10 Enterprise 1607

Tags: onedrive, windows-10-v1607

Just installed Windows 10 Enterprise on a box and joined it to the domain and realized that OneDrive is not integrated with Windows Explorer. I can download the Windows Store OneDrive App, logon and see my files but I need it integrated with the Windows Explorer. On other computers with Windows 10 1607 that is not enterprise OneDrive folder is in the Windows Explorer but that is not the case with the Enterprise version.

Is there a way to integrate it or is integration disabled by design on Enterprise version?

Comment: What's with the down vote, what is the problem with this question?

Comment: Are you sure it's not disabled by GPO?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I checked Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\OneDrive

Comment: download and install the client: https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-my/download/

Comment: @magicandre1981 That didn't work...

Comment: what happens? Error message?

Comment: There is no download for Windows and the download for earlier versions will not install on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by running OneDriveSetup.exe from %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\17.3.6517.0809 as Administrator.

Comment: worked for me like a charm. Thanks this saved my quite some time searching for a solution.

Comment: Worked for me also.

Comment: Do not work for me :/ Ok, I'm in 2022 and in Windows 11 XD